# Mostrar todos los div que contienen la misma etiqueta

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una especie de buscador de etiquetas pero el problema es que solo me muestra un resultado.

Si busco 'hola' debería salirme los 3, ya que los 3 tienen la misma etiqueta lo mismo con 'color' pero sólo me sale uno como ya lo dije, igualmente también quisiera saber cómo buscar varias etiquetas a la vez, ejemplo buscar **hola, -otra etiqueta - etc...** y salga todos, ya lo intenté y no funciona a menos que haga esto al momento de buscar **red + .blue** me mostrará finalmente el div class blue.

No tengo idea cuando usar querySelector y querySelectorAll, intenté con este último también, pero no funciona como lo hace **querySelector**

```js
function buscar(){
var buscar = document.getElementById("search").value;
var result = document.querySelector('.' + buscar);
result.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.hola{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
display: none;
}
.red{
background-color: red;
}
.blue{
background-color: blue;
}
.yellow{
background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Buscar...">
<button onclick="buscar()">Buscar</button>

<br/>
<br/>

<div class="hola color red"></div>
<div class="hola color blue "></div>
<div class="hola color yellow"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`querySelector` sólo devuelve el primer elemento que cumple con el selector. `querySelectorAll` devuelve una lista con todos los elementos que cumplen con el selector. Entonces para cambiar el `display` de los diferentes resultados debes usar un bucle.

Al hacer `result.style.display = "block";` siendo `result` un array, obtendrás un error. Debes crear un bucle que atraviese todos los elementos.

```js
function buscar() {
  var buscar = document.getElementById("search").value;
  var result = document.querySelectorAll('.' + buscar);
  for (let x = 0; x < result.length; x++) {
    result[x].style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.hola {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Buscar...">
<button onclick="buscar()">Buscar</button>

<br/>
<br/>

<div class="hola color red"></div>
<div class="hola color blue "></div>
<div class="hola color yellow"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Según la documentación oficial, `querySelector()`:

> Devuelve el primer elemento del documento que coincida con el grupo especificado de selectores.

Es por ello que tan solo consigues mostrar uno de los 3 `<div>` que quieres que se muestren, el rojo, que es el primero.

Para seleccionar todos los elementos que coincidan con tu selector, debes usar la función `querySelectorAll()`

> El método querySelectorAll() de un Element devuelve una NodeList
>   estática (no viva) que representa una lista de elementos del documento
>   que coinciden con el grupo de selectores indicados.

Una vez conseguidos todos los elementos tan solo te queda iterar por ellos para ir colocándole a cada uno el `display: block`.

Para buscar más de una etiqueta debes especificar un caracter que sirva de separador, para saber donde empieza una etiqueta y termina la otra. En mi caso usé el espacio, de tal manera que si buscas "red blue" primero buscará todos los elementos con la clase `.red` y los mostrará, y después hará lo mismo con todos los elementos con la clase `.blue`.

```js
function buscar(){

  var coleccion = document.querySelectorAll('.hola');
  ocultar_elementos(coleccion);
  var buscar = document.getElementById("search").value;
  var trozos = buscar.split(' ');

  trozos.forEach(function (trozo) {
    var results = document.querySelectorAll('.' + trozo);

    results.forEach(function(element) {
      element.style.display = 'block';
    });  
  });
}

function ocultar_elementos(coleccion) {
  coleccion.forEach(function(element) {
    element.style.display = 'none';
  });  
}
```

```css
.hola{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
display: none;
}
.red{
background-color: red;
}
.blue{
background-color: blue;
}
.yellow{
background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Buscar...">
<button onclick="buscar()">Buscar</button>

<br/>
<br/>

<div class="hola color red"></div>
<div class="hola color blue "></div>
<div class="hola color yellow"></div>
```

Comment: Y cómo hago para ocultar el resultado al momento de realizar otra busqueda?

Comment: Lo único que tendrías que hacer es, al inicio de la función, ocultar todos los `<divs>`. Edité mi respuesta y ya que se trata de otra funcionalidad aparte hice una nueva función que recibe una colección, la recorre y oculta cada uno de sus elementos.

Answer (score 2):

[document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

> Devuelve el primer elemento del documento (...) que coincida con el grupo especificado de selectores.

[document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

> Devuelve una NodeList estática (no viva) que representa una lista de elementos del documento que coinciden con el grupo de selectores indicados.

Teniendo en cuenta esto podés armar el query con comas para incluir todas las clases, o simplemente concatenar las palabras/clases para que traiga resultados exactos.

versión OR ( uno o dos o tres)

`document.querySelectorAll('.red, .blue, .yellow')`

```js
function buscar() {
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/32204734/1423096
  var buscar = document.getElementById("search").value.match(/[a-z'\-]+/gi);
  var queBuscar = `.${buscar.join(', .')}`;
  console.log(buscar, queBuscar)
  var limpia = document.querySelectorAll('.filtrar > div');
  limpia.forEach(function(res) {
    res.style.display = "none";
  })

  var result = document.querySelectorAll(queBuscar);
  result.forEach(function(res) {
    res.style.display = "block";
  })
}
```

```css
.hola {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Buscar...">
<button onclick="buscar()">Buscar</button>

<br/>
<br/>
<div class=filtrar>
  <div class="hola color red"></div>
  <div class="hola color blue "></div>
  <div class="hola color yellow"></div>
</div>
```

---

versión AND ( uno y dos y tres )

`document.querySelectorAll('.hola.red')`

```js
function buscar() {
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/32204734/1423096
  var buscar = document.getElementById("search").value.match(/[a-z'\-]+/gi);
  var queBuscar = `.${buscar.join('.')}`;
    
  console.log(buscar, queBuscar)
  var limpia = document.querySelectorAll('.filtrar > div');
  limpia.forEach(function(res) {
    res.style.display = "none";
  })

  var result = document.querySelectorAll(queBuscar);
  result.forEach(function(res) {
    res.style.display = "block";
  })
}
```

```css
.hola {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Buscar...">
<button onclick="buscar()">Buscar</button>

<br/>
<br/>
<div class=filtrar>
  <div class="hola color red"></div>
  <div class="hola color blue "></div>
  <div class="hola color yellow"></div>
</div>
```

referencia separar string por palabras:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660756/how-to-split-words-using-javascript/32204734#32204734

Answer (score 1):

Esto lo puedes hacer de forma muy simple con jquery, con la funcion `css()` para cambiar el estilo de los `<div>`, el código queda de la siguiente forma:

```js
function buscar(){
  ocultar();
  var valor = document.getElementById("search").value;
  //para poder buscar por varios campos separados por ,
  var abuscar = valor.split(" ").join("").split(",");
  for(i=0;i<abuscar.length;i++){
    $("."+abuscar[i]).css("display", "block");
  }
  
}
//ocultar todos los divs para realizar una nueva busqueda
function ocultar(){
  $("div").css("display", "none");
}
ocultar();
```

```css
.hola{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
.red{
background-color: red;
}
.blue{
background-color: blue;
}
.yellow{
background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Buscar...">
<button onclick="buscar()">Buscar</button>

<br/>
<br/>

<div class="hola color red"></div>
<div class="hola color blue "></div>
<div class="hola color yellow"></div>
```

Explicando un poco, con jquery puedes buscar elementos que contengan una clase con `$(".clase")`, luego en la función `css()` puedes ocultar y mostrar los elementos cambiando el `display` de `none` a `block`, no olvides ocultar todos los elementos al hacer una nueva búsqueda con una función.

Para el buscar por mas de un valor separado por "," (como "red, blue") y quitar los espacios en blanco puedes usar `split()`.

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.